# Is there a API to read a line from a reader, but to limit the length of returned line?

Tags: go

The prototype would be:

```
 (reader *Reader) ReadLineWithMaxLength (delim byte, max int) (line []byte, err error)
```

It returns a line when either the *delim* is found or *max* length is reached.

Comment: If you're reading text, remember that utf8 doesn't always consist of single byte characters. You might end up chopping an otherwise valid character if you always delimit on a single byte.

Comment: @JeffreyMartinez, sadly, most Golang APIs use byte instead of rune as delims.

Comment: @TL That's ok, learn from past mistakes and use rune for yours to make it better ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a direct function, but implementing one using `io.LimitReader` is straightforward.

```
func ReadLimitedLine(r io.Reader, delim byte, max int64) ([]byte, error) {
    l, err := bufio.NewReader(io.LimitReader(r, max)).ReadBytes(delim)
    if err != nil && err != io.EOF {
        return nil, err
    }

    // ReadBytes includes the delimiter in return value
    return bytes.TrimSuffix(l, []byte{delim}), nil
}
```

Comment: Be *very* careful adding "temporary" buffering like this. In general, a `bufio.Reader` may read ahead on `r` and if you then ignore/discard the buffer and go back to reading from `r` you will skip those bytes (the [`Buffered`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader.Buffered) method will tell you how many such bytes there are).